# FlexUnit Build Failed

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, unit-testing, flexbuilder, flexunit

I have problem when I try to run unit test when I embed an Image

```
        [Embed(source="assets/Pen.png")] 
    [Bindable]
    private var PenImageClass:Class;
    private var penCursor:Bitmap= (new PenImageClass());
```

the error message is :

> unable to resolve 'assets/Pen.png' for transcoding

but when I commented the [Embed(source="assets/Pen.png")] It works correctly.
>
How can I resolve this.

Comment: You may check the image path or the image name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add the assets folder directly beside the as file, the Flex Unit should understand that.